# Can a minor possess a handgun on private property in Oregon?

Tags: minor, firearms, oregon, second-amendment

Can a minor possess a handgun on private property in Oregon (outside any city limits) with the consent of his parents and the property owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are minors allowed to possess handguns in Oregon?

Yes, with exceptions, although they may not purchase or own handguns, and are not permitted to conceal carry handguns.

Oregon Revised Statutes § 166.470 prohibits any person from intentionally selling, delivering, or otherwise transferring a handgun to anyone under 21 years of age, ORS § 166.470(1)(a), except the temporary transfer of any firearm to a minor for hunting, target practice, or any other lawful purpose. ORS § 166.470(3)(b). The other primary statute that is relevant is Oregon Revised Statutes § 166.250 which also provides that minors may possess any firearm temporarily for hunting, target practice, or any other lawful purpose. ORS § 166.250(2)(a)(B).

But, despite this general rule, a minor may not possess a firearm if they are under 18 years of age, and while a minor, committed the equivalent of an adult felony or a misdemeanor involving violence, within four years of being charged with possession. ORS § 166.250(1)(c).

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_laws_in_Oregon)).